# Multi-line block select using the keyboard in IntelliJ IDEA on a Mac OS X

Tags: java, macos, android-studio, intellij-idea, intellij-13

I've recently switched from Eclipse to IntelliJ IDEA 13.  I use the VI keybindings.

One non-vi thing I am used to doing in Eclipse is using <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>↑</kbd> / <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>↓</kbd> to block a few lines of text.  The behaviour of this text selection in Eclipse is the same as almost every other text input widget I've ever used.  Typically I do one of two things after making the selection - delete this block or comment it out (<kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>/</kbd>).

I have no found equivalent keyboard-only multi-line selection function in IntelliJ IDEA 13.

<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>↑</kbd> does not start a block selection - it seems to page the cursor up and down the screen.

If I use the mouse to start making a selection, then the arrow keys *do* extend the selection.  However, I'm unable to *start* a selection using the keyboard alone.

I'm aware of the <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>W</kbd> *ever-outward-growing smart element selection* - but if you then use the arrow keys, the selection is lost, not extended.

How can I start and then extend a selection region across multiple lines using the keyboard only on Mac OS X (that works with the VI keybindings enabled)?

Answer (score 8):

#### Multi-line caret

For Mac, you can use <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>⌘</kbd>(Hold)+<kbd>↑ / ↓</kbd>.
For Windows, replace the <kbd>⌘</kbd> with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>.

<kbd>ESC</kbd> will end multi-line mode.

#### Change Multi-caret Hotkey

To add a custom Keymap, <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>, type `keymap` and click on the one with `Settings` as subtext. Search for `Clone Caret Above` and `Clone Caret Below`.

I mapped mine to <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>↑ / ↓</kbd>.

#### Bonus

Try holding combinations of <kbd>⌘</kbd>, <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>, and arrows for improved selection power.

Comment: As you mentionned it works for Windows with [CTRL]+[CTRL] (hold) + [↑ / ↓]

Comment: flawless answer! Saved the day!

Comment: You saved me alot of time.

Comment: How does one Cmd+Cmd (Hold)? Can someone please explain?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you need to map it. In the default key mapping <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>↑</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>↓</kbd> work as expected (i.e. as you describe). I do not have the vi mapping available to check it. Go into *Settings > [IDE Settings] > Keymap*. In the Keymap, go to "Editor Actions". Configure the "Down with Selection" and "Up with Selection" options. This may mean removing the <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>↑</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>↓</kbd> mappings from something else.

Comment: `Down with selection` is ^⇧↓ - but that key combination doesn't appear to do the trick.  If I search based on a keystroke, I find that ⇧↓ matches an entry simply called `Key` registered via the IdeaVim plugin (along with perhaps a hundred other keystrokes).  Unfortunately, right clicking and attempting to edit the list is futile because the length of the list is taller than the screen, and it won't scroll. :-\ Perhaps time to log a bug with JetBrains...

Answer (score 1):

I use the IdeaVIM plugin on Mac OS and I can increase or decrease my selection with the keyboard only with <kbd>alt</kbd>-<kbd>Up</kbd>/<kbd>Down</kbd>.

It is possible I customized the VIM keymap to this, can't remember if it is default or not. However, the editor action you are looking for in the keymap settings is "Select Word at Caret" and "Unselect Word at Caret". Repeatedly pressing the keystroke smartly selects/unselects the text. It almost always selects what I want.

[image]

Comment: `Select Word at Caret` is originally bound to ⌘W, so this is the _ever-outward-growing smart element selection_ I spoke of.  I just want to block the whole current line, and extend that selection _line-by-line_ in the direction I move the cursor.

Comment: I've ended up changing the binding for ⌘↑ and ⌘↓ to to be `Toggle Sticky Selection` - this gives me an easy key-stroke to start the selection and then continue with the arrow keys.

Answer (score 1):

You can use alt+Up/Down/Right/Left or alt+mouse-select to block select on mac in IntelliJ

Comment: On windows, alt+up/down is for Previous/Next method. I believe this is default settings.